# Jpanel repaint with mouse movement event

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, repaint

Ok here is the thing I am making a function grapher and I want when you move your mouse over a line it will show the coordinates.  So I set up just a basic drawstring on the panel to show the mouse coords but I can not get to repaint well normally. It seems to be painting just fine but it is not clearing the contents before painting here is the code I have thus far.

```
public class Grapher extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener{
private final int BORDER_GAP = 15;
private final int MAX_SCORE = 20;
private final int PREF_WIDTH = 800;
private final int PREF_HEIGHT = 650;
private final int GRAPH_POINT_WIDTH = 12;
private static final int GRAPH_INTERVAL = 15;

private static Point mse;

private List<Point> values;

public Grapher(List<Point> values) {
    setMse(new Point(0,0));
    this.values = values;
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    float xScale = ((float) getWidth() - 2 * BORDER_GAP) / (values.size()-1);
    float yScale = ((float) getHeight() - 2 * BORDER_GAP) / (MAX_SCORE-1);

    g2d.drawString(xScale+"", 50, 50);
    g2d.drawString(yScale+"", 50, 70);
    g2d.drawString(getWidth()/2+"", 50, 90);
    g2d.drawString(mse.x +"  " + mse.y, 50, 30);

    //create axis
    g2d.setColor(new Color(0x7e7e7e));
    //x line
    g2d.drawLine(BORDER_GAP, (getHeight() - BORDER_GAP)/2, getWidth() - BORDER_GAP, (getHeight() - BORDER_GAP)/2);
    //y line
    g2d.drawLine(getWidth()/2, getHeight() - BORDER_GAP, getWidth()/2, BORDER_GAP);

}

public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(PREF_WIDTH, PREF_HEIGHT);
}

private static void createAndShowGui(){
    List<Point> values = new ArrayList<Point>();
    int maxDataPoints = 20;

    for (int i = -GRAPH_INTERVAL; i <= GRAPH_INTERVAL; i++) {
        String val = "";
        try {
            val = EquationSolver.solveEquation(variableReplace('x', i));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            val ="0";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(i + "= " + val);
        values.add(new Point(i, Integer.parseInt(val)));
    }

    Grapher panel = new Grapher(values);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grapher");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    //frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            createAndShowGui();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    setMse(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    removeAll();
    repaint();      
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    setMse(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    //repaint();        
}
```

Ok here is some images as to what the code is doing
the top numbers are the mouse position.
A fresh start to program: http://snag.gy/BFrUj.jpg.
After i move the mouse around a little: http://snag.gy/lNqie.jpg

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the major problem you are having is related to `g.dispose()`

The graphics context is shared, meaning that if you dispose of the graphics context, nothing else can paint to it.  Unless you create the context, you should never dispose it

Your other problem is, you are not actually calling `super.paintComponent`, which is responsible for preparing the graphics context for painting (by clearing the are to be painted), but instead, you are calling `super.paintComponents(g)` ... not the **s** at the end...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Keyboard malfunction...serious, my keyboard has stopped working...had to switch ;)

Comment: Tried removing the g.dispose() still am getting the same issue.

Comment: And the second part?  Calling `super.paintComponents` instead of `super.paintComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I draw straight onto the panel it does that overlaying effect but if i add a white rectangle as a background that solves the problem.

```
...  
float xScale = ((float) getWidth() - 2 * BORDER_GAP) / (values.size()-1);
float yScale = ((float) getHeight() - 2 * BORDER_GAP) / (MAX_SCORE-1);

g2d.setColor(Color.white);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
g2d.setColor(new Color(0x7e7e7e));

g2d.drawString(xScale+"", 50, 50);
g2d.drawString(yScale+"", 50, 70);
g2d.drawString(getWidth()/2+"", 50, 90);
g2d.drawString(mse.x +"  " + mse.y, 50, 30);
...
```

That appears to be a fix for the problem. If anyone can explain why drawing straight to the panel overlays or has a better solution please do answer.

Comment: No, it's not.  It's a hack to get around the fact that you are calling `super.paintComponents` instead of `super.paintComponent` which I highlighted in my answer